# Does the EU flight delay compensation apply to connecting flights as well?

Tags: transit, eu, compensation, passenger-rights

There has [recently been](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89432/lufthansa-denied-boarding-after-coming-from-another-delayed-lufthansa-flight-for) a question about a traveler who missed his connecting flight within the EU and was forced to take a different flight at a later time. In that scenario, would the EU's flight delay compensation scheme kick in as well? Or does it only apply to point-to-point flights?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [EU's Air Passenger Rights FAQ](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/faq/index_en.htm):

> **Do I have any rights if I am not allowed to board my connecting flight
>   because I arrived late at the gates due to a delay with the first
>   flight?**
>
> YES - if the flights are part of a single reservation**, the carrier has
>   to offer you the option between the reimbursement of your ticket and a
>   return flight to the airport of departure at the earliest opportunity
>   or re-routing to your final destination at the earliest opportunity or
>   re-routing at a later date at your convenience under comparable
>   transport conditions, subject to the availability of seats. **In case
>   you are re-routed and you reach your final destination with a delay of
>   3 hours or more you are entitled to compensation.

So the answer is **yes**, they do apply as normal.

Comment: I would be grateful if you (or anyone) could clarify what _compensation_ means in this case.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The last FAQ on that page says that "extraordinary circumstances" like bad weather are exempted.

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, weather doesn't count and the vast majority of all delays are due to weather.

Comment: @PsySp [Compensation](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#compensation).

Comment: @Neusser Thank you.  In my case I was denied boarding (fall under 1st category), but I did not receive any compensation.

Comment: @PsySp Did you claim any? What flight was that? Which company?

Comment: @Neusser I am the OP from the original linked question. It was a Lufthansa flight from A to B through Frankfurt (all within Europe). I file a complain after the incident. But there was absolutely no answer from their side.

Comment: As already mentioned in the answers to your question, you weren't denied boarding, you missed the connecting flight. This is a big difference.

Comment: @dunni he was denied boarding (see the text of my answer)